# Xpath for facebook newsfeed box is not working

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to perform following using selenium webdriver and Java :

1. Login to Facebook
2. Click on user name
3. Post word "How are you!!" as newsfeed

Above first 2 steps are working but 3rd don't. It is unable to find newsfeed text box.

I am trying with this xpath : `"//*[text()=\"What's on your mind?\"]"`

I can not use class or id as it is dynamic and change every time.

**Note :** I have test this xpath with firepath and at there it says valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
"//*[@placeholder=\"What's on your mind?\"]"
```

Because, it is not `text` but an attribute named `placeholder`.

Comment: Sure. Let me try.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try `"//*[contains(text(), 'What's on your mind?')]"`